# Using Tumblr API to pull first sentence from post captions

Tags: javascript, api, jquery, tumblr

I've got a quick question regarding the Tumblr API. I'm working on a website for a photographer and would like to use that API to stream the first 50 - 100 words from her two most recent posts on her homepage. The JS file I've written streams the captions from the two most recent posts, but I can't figure out how to pull only the first fifty or so words. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

```
function buildURL (blogname, apiKey) {
    return 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/'
        + blogname
        + '.tumblr.com/posts?api_key='
        + apiKey
        + '&limit=2'
        + '&callback=?'
}

var key = '/* Put your Tumblr Key Here */'

var url = buildURL('ehockstein', key)

$(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        console.log(data)

        createPosts(data.response.posts)

    })
})

function createPosts (posts) {

    posts.forEach(function (post) {

        var postElement = $('<div class="post"></div>')
        postElement.addClass(post.type)

        if (post.type === 'photo') {

            var caption = post.caption

            postElement.append(caption)

        }

        postElement.appendTo('#tumblr-posts')

    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tumblr API doesn't support returning partial captions. You'll need to pull the full caption from the API and create a substring in your own code that contains the first 50 - 100 words.

This would look something like this:

```
var shortCaption = caption.substring(0, 499)
```

That takes the first 500 characters, which will give you close to 100 words.

You could then append `shortCaption` to `postElement` (as opposed to appending `caption`).

You can learn more about how substring works [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

Comment: thanks for the help! i wasn't aware of substring before this so your advice was quite helpful. i ended up using indexOf to slice between words, so the final solution was: 

`var spaceIndex = post.caption.indexOf('.', 100),
                caption = post.caption.slice(0, spaceIndex)

            postElement.append(caption + '...')`

take care!

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out and came up with a better solution.